# PHP forms and same names

Tags: php, jquery, html

Hi I have a page that contains several different forms all of which are shown/hidden on the press of the appropriate button.

Now all of them need to include some fields that are retrieved by php from the database but **the problem is that my jquery code then fails to hide the fields that are declared later on.**

Heres an example of my code:

```
<form action="controlPanel.php" method="post">
    <input class="inputFields" type="text" name="fileName" />
    <input class="inputFields" type="text" name="fname" />
    <select class="styled-select" id="nameDropdown" name='nameDropdown'>
    <option value="0"><span class="formatFreeTxt">Choose a name</span></option>
    <?php
        foreach ($GLOBALS['myDB']->getList('2') as $i) {
            echo "<option value='" . $i['email'] . "'>" . $i['fname'] . " " . $i['lname'] . "</option>";
         }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input class="inputFields" type="submit" name="textForm" />
</form>
```

And then I have another form on the div under the above. Like that:

```
<form action="controlPanel.php" method="post">
    <input class="inputFields" type="text" name="textName" />
    <input class="inputFields" type="text" name="lname" />
    <select class="styled-select" id="nameDropdown" name='nameDropdown'>
    <option value="0"><span class="formatFreeTxt">Choose a name</span></option>
    <?php
        foreach ($GLOBALS['myDB']->getList('2') as $i) {
            echo "<option value='" . $i['email'] . "'>" . $i['fname'] . " " . $i['lname'] . "</option>";
         }
    ?>
    </select>
    <input class="inputFields" type="submit" name="nextTxtForm" />
</form>
```

My JQuery code is:

```
function showHideBenef()
 {
       if($('#nameDropdown').is(':visible'))
       {
          $('#nameDropdown').fadeOut();
          $('#nameTable').fadeIn();
          $('#toggleButton').attr('value', 'Choose from existing ones');
          $('#chooseTxt').html('New Beneficiary Form');

       }
       else
       {
           $('#nameDropdown').fadeIn();
           $('#nameTable').fadeOut();
           $('#toggleButton').attr('value', 'OR Add a new one');
       }

  }
```

Is there any way to make this work without changing the names of each field so that I can actually catch the different posts without the need for checking all the different field names?

Comment: @radashk I've just added the JQuery code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of all duplicate `id` attribute values, and then you can use the `name` attribute values:

```
function showHideBenef () {

  var nameDropdown = $( '[name="nameDropdown"]' );

  if ( nameDropdown.is( ':visible' ) ) {

    nameDropdown.fadeOut();

    // Not sure what the following elements are, might need to use
    // `name` attr or classes to select them.

    $( '#nameTable' ).fadeIn();

    $( '#toggleButton' ).attr( 'value', 'Choose from existing ones' );

    $( '#chooseTxt' ).html('New Beneficiary Form');

  }


  else {

    nameDropdown.fadeIn();

    $( '#nameTable' ).fadeOut();

    $( '#toggleButton' ).attr( 'value', 'OR Add a new one' );

  }

}
// showHideBenef
```

Answer (score 1):

the issue here is you have multiple input elements with same id & name which is not good.

why not have them as array?

so elements in form1 would be

```
<input type="text" name="firstform[fname]" id="firstform_fname"/>
```

and the elements in form2 would be

```
<input type="text" name="secondform[fname]" id="secondform_fname"/>
```

in the php script, you can get the values of the forms from $_POST['firstform'] and  $_POST['secondform']

Answer (score 0):

Just give each form a unique id attribute.

Answer (score 0):

i think set id attribute

like this

```
<form action="controlPanel.php" method="post"  id="form1">
```

or

```
<form action="controlPanel.php" method="post" id="form2">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can give each input an ID attribute and use jQuery to hide/show based on the ID.

Use a prefix for the IDs so you can distinguish between the inputs such as id="textFormFileName" and id="nextTxtFormFileName"

Answer (score 0):

Ok its probably not the optimal solution but I ended up wrapping everything in a div element and then I use JQuery to hide the whole div...That way I can keep having duplicate names in different forms and jquery works fine as long as you give the divs a different id..

Thank you all for your answers!

Comment: Duplicate `name` attribute values are fine. Duplicate `id` attribute values are invalid HTML and will cause various problems.

Comment: @JMM Yeah I know but i only need the name attribute so that I can refer to it when I catch the Post in php :)